# Is it safe to build a game with javascript + electron + three.js?

Tags: javascript, three.js, electron

Nothing really massive like the scale of a MMORPG, but a small game like faster than light.

Anyone can open dev tools, so I was wondering if its possible to add protection against cheat engine or if I can implement something that would prevent users from running their own javascript into the game.

I also understand that writing games in javascript is probably not the best solution because its very inefficient, but this is something I want to try.

Comment: No you can not prevent users from coding against it.

Comment: Unity supports JavaScript. This is not really a Stackoverflow qualified question.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

According to [this thread in the developer forum](https://discuss.atom.io/t/a-way-to-prevent-developer-tools/29746/5), there is a way to force the dev tools to close whenever they open using the following code:

```
win.webContents.on("devtools-opened", () => {
  win.webContents.closeDevTools();
});
```

Comment: :o ty. This was what I was looking for

Comment: A Greasemonkey script would clobber this.

Comment: I was under the impression that Greasemonkey was a firefox extension, whereas electron js was for making desktop apps

Comment: Ah, I see. Point taken

Comment: You could also rely on the server to update player infos, using client to send player inputs only, thus preventing any manual change from devtools

Answer (score 0):

If it will be a simple game without inApp purshases, then you don't need to prevent players from hacking. They can enjoy it in any way then, even in such way.